# Star Trek-themed parody of "Bohemian Rhapsody"

Tags: star-trek, music-identification

While queuing for the bus to work this morning, I randomly remembered one of the songs my dad subjected me to during my childhood. It was a Star Trek-themed parody of Bohemian Rhapsody, specifically, the opera section in the middle. I would have heard it sometime around 2005, give or take a couple of years, and I'm guessing my dad probably found it on LimeWire somewhere.

I don't remember all the lyrics, but it began with Kirk declaring:

> I am the captain of the starship Enterprise

The "Bismillah" "No! We will not let you go!" section was replaced with Sulu suggesting successively-faster warp speeds, to which Kirk would respond with something like "No! That will be too damn slow!" The song ended with Spock declaring that something or other would "be illogical to me... to me... to meeeeeee~", followed by a brief section of the guitar solo as the track faded out.

Would anyone happen to know what this parody was, and who it was by? I'd ask my dad but I don't imagine he even remembers the song in question anymore.

Comment: https://www.stlyrics.com/songs/w/weirdalyankovic4128/startrekrhapsody214238.html

Comment: I'll accept the downvotes as valid. I probably should have Googled the lyrics before asking it here, but I expected it to be more obscure than it actually was.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCARADb9asE) was better than what you were looking for, terrible yes, but still better.

Comment: @Pelinore I'm familiar with Star Trekkin', so I didn't need to ask about that one.

Comment: I hate to be "that guy", but googling `star trek bohemian rhapsody I am the captain of the starship Enterprise` returns the song in numerous results on the first page. You don't even need quotes or anything. Google is your friend. It indexes almost the entire web. Nothing is too "obscure" to a computer. It's all just bits.

Comment: @Pelinore I think OP wanted something a little more operatic, perhaps similar to [this treatment of Wrath of Khan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iauuuhpSfRQ).  (though it's better in the original Klingon)

Comment: @only_pro to be fair sometimes its very hard to find the right search terms for what your looking for, given in this case not so much.

Comment: @AC : a new one to me ;D

Comment: The lighting on this one is so good https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bl5TUw7sUBs

Comment: @Revenant True. I am being fair. In this case I just searched exactly what OP was asking for. Verbatim.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is it.

According to the description is was recorded in 1996 by Kevin Barbare. I don't know how to answer without just including a link.

Here's a [direct link to the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xU2MQ03d0bg) on Youtube if it doesn't play here.

> Kirk: I am the captain of the Starship Enterprise.
>   Spock:  Captain Kirk: This is Spock.
>   Please step on the transporter.
>   Scotty: Dilithium crystals!
>   Hit by Klingon missiles!
>   No!
>   McCoy:  I'm a doctor!
>   Kirk:   Not an actor!
>   McCoy:  Not a milkman!
>   Kirk:   What does that mean?
>   McCoy:  And I'm sorry -- He's dead, Jim.
>   Chekov: Photon torpedo . . . !
>   Kirk:   Lieutenant Uhura,
>   Open hailing frequencies
>   Uhura:  Yes, Captain Kirk,
>   Opening hailing frequencies, sir
>   Kirk:   Let's boldly go where no one's gone before!
>   Ha ha ha ha ha ha . . .
>   Beam me up, Mr. Scott;
>   Sulu, go to warp!
>   Sulu:   Warp three, sir.
>   Kirk:   No! That will be way too slow!
>   Sulu:   Warp four, sir?
>   Kirk:   That still is way too slow!
>   Sulu:   Warp five, sir.
>   Kirk:   It still is too damn slow!
>   Sulu:   Warp six.
>   Kirk:   It's too damn slow!
>   Sulu:   Warp seven?
>   Kirk:   It's still damn slow!
>   Chorus: It's too damn slow . . . !
>   Kirk:   No, no, no, no, no, no, no!
>   Mr. Chekov, Mr. Chekov --
>   Chekov: I am firing torpedo!
>   Spock:  That will not work and would be illogical
>   To me, to me, to me . . . !

Some sources credit Weird Al and others claim it was originally created on something called "The Hill-Man Morning Show".

Comment: Some lyrics here; https://www.allthelyrics.com/lyrics/weird_al_yankovic/star_trek_rhapsody-lyrics-1162801.html

Comment: Yep, that looks like the one. Thanks!

Comment: It's not by Weird Al. There was at time where every bad parody on the internet was posted under Weird Al, just to get the views. http://www.com-www.com/weirdal/notbyal.html

Comment: And the video doesn't work.

Comment: Refresh it or something because it does work. It appears to be an original work and has been an upload on the channel "KEVIN BARBARE" since 2007.

Comment: Oh my god the awful, it's awfully awful, it's as awful as something awful from Awful Town that just won first prize for awful at the International Festival of Awful, and holds the chair of of awful at the awful university.

Comment: Well.  That was.... horrible.

Comment: I think it's quite catchy ;)

Comment: Oh, Weird Al did do Bohemian Rhapsody, just not a Star Trek based one. ([Here](https://youtu.be/QZsN3S0WJ_o).)

Comment: Oh man I haven't heard this version in years. LMAO

Answer (score -3):

The parody you are looking for is likely [Star Trek Rhapsody](https://www.stlyrics.com/songs/w/weirdalyankovic4128/startrekrhapsody214238.html) allegedly by Weird Al Yankovik. However, as suggested by other users, it's probably not the complete truth.

> Kirk:  I am the captain of the Starship Enterprise.

Comment: Are you sure it's Weird Al Yankovic's? Doesn't sound like one of his parodies at all.

Comment: The linked website states it as that.

Comment: Weird Al would never have released something so bad. This would have ended his career. And there's no accordion. :)

Comment: He doesn't _always_ use an accordion.  But yeah, this is definitely not him.

Comment: Added this in the answer

Comment: @NeoDarwin I see that, but that doesn't mean it's true. I think it's wrongly credited.